# Is it possible to switch between multiple useLazyQueries in a switch case?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

So i have a page with 4 tabs that users can click, on each tab click this needs to trigger different useLazyQueries for my graphql react app. All 4 queries have data that will be displayed with the same columns so i am trying to avoid making 4 different components for each tab.

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
  // DATA FETCH FOR RAW MATERIALS & PACKAGING
  const [getData, { data, error, refetch, loading }] = () => {
    switch (listType) {
    case "List One": {
      useLazyQueryOne({
        variables: {}
       })
    }
    case "List Two": {
      useLazyQueryTw-o({
        variables: {}
       })
    }
    ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're not allowed to make conditional calls to a hook. Instead make the parameters to `useLazyQuery` depend on `listType`.